# How can I display a local image in my Node-RED UI dashboard?

Tags: user-interface, node-red, node-redis

i created a dashboard for a project on my node-red ui screen, and node-red is working locally on my computer now I want to add a logo to the bottom left of my project, but I don't know how to do it, can you help me with this
how to add local image in node-red ui